# Get Category URL multistore and multisite

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I have a 2 website.

1. https://website.com (Default Website)
2. https://site.website.com (Secondary Website)

Now I'm accessing the admin panel using the `https://website.com/admin/catalog/category...` Now when I save the categories I have an observer that generate the menu for each of this site. Take note that each website is using different root category. Upon clicking the save category button it generate an html file which contains the list of categories for each website. But the problem now is when I checked the generated url for `https://site.website.com/` it generates a category url of `https://website.com/secondsitecategory` which I expect should be `https://site.website.com/secondsitecategory`.

Below is my code to retrieve the category in Magento 2

```
$subcategories = $category->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStoreId($store->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->load();
```

Note: the `$category` in `$category->collection()` is the root category of every website. I tried using emulator like

> $this->_emulator->startEnvironmentEmulation($store->getId(), \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

before every `$category->getCollection()` but it's not working. Would any one of you have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to set store before loading collection.

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
*/

protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
  $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

now you can set your current store like

```
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('YOUR_STORE_ID');
```

Comment: This don't work. Tried it and it's still returning the main website url and not the url of the expected store for the secondary website

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `joinUrlRewrite()` to `collection` for  getting the store repective URL

```
    $subcategories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStoreId($store->getId())
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
        ->joinUrlRewrite() // add This
        ->load();
```